# Why out of all data types int is OS or compiler dependant

Tags: c++, operating-system

I am wondering, out of all data types that are usually available in C/C++, why some of them are  OS or compiler dependent?

Is there any logical reason to this, or it's just by design?

Comment: What data types _aren't_ compiler dependent?

Comment: For one, ecause there are 8-bit, 16-bit, 24-bit, .... computers

Comment: "int" is not the only one. For example, "bool" is usually 1-byte, but there are implementations with 4-byte "bool" too.

Comment: (What's really irritating is that `long` is also platform-dependent, as are many others, with no consistent way to specify stuff in a platform-independent fashion.)

Comment: so after reading all the comments, I can see that most of the data types are compiler dependent, and yes I read it somewhere just now that, standards just define things such as 

"specification is that int has the natural size suggested by the system architecture (one "word") and the four integer types char, short, int and long must each one be at least as large as the one preceding it, with char being always one byte in size."

So it seems only guarantee with standard data types is that char will be of 1 byte?

Comment: Does anybody happen to know reason for this? One thing I read here is, It allows compilers to optimize codes with data types that are world-length dependent??

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Because C/C++ runs on lots of different machine architectures.

So `int` is defined as "the natural size" for a machine - this lets the compiler generate code that runs well on that machine.

On modern machines, that is usually 32 bits or 64. On older machines, it was 16 bits.
On some machines (you can look it up) it was 24 or 36 bits.

The C standard is very careful in its' definitions of these types.
It requires some things (like "`long` cannot be smaller than `int`") while leaving other things up to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is not special in this regard. Every integral data type is compiler-dependent. There are minimum ranges for each type, and the types have an order of non-decreasing size: `char`->`short`->`int`->`long`->`long long`. A conforming implementation could make all of them 64 bits wide.

Answer (score -1):

The `int` type is supposed to be the natural size for the architecture you are using. So on a 32 bit machine, `int` is typically 32 bits. On 64 bit, `int` is typically 64 bit. (32 bit OS on 64 bit machine would probably be 32 bit `int`.)

The reason for this is efficiency. Oftentimes, the maximum representible quantity doesn't actually matter, and you just want to use the most efficient type. The most common example is loops.

```
for(int i=0; i< NUM_ITER; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```

For most loops, the number of iterations is typically not that large. But even if you know you will not need to loop more than 255 times, using, say, `unsigned char` as your loop counter might actually be less efficient in terms of register usage and such.

EDIT: Here is another example. Suppose the word size is 4 bytes, and you had some function that starts as follows:

```
void foo() {
  static char x;
  static char y;
  // ...
}
```

A naive compilation of that might put the variable `x` at some address, say `0x0F00`. Then the variable `y` would be placed by the naive compilation at address `0x0F01` since `x` needs only 1 byte. But on many architectures, memory accesses are optimized for addresses which are 4-byte aligned, so accessing `y` might be implemented as a 4-byte access to/from `0x0F00`, then discarding 3 of those bytes. This is obviously wasteful in terms of bandwidth consumption, but the bigger issue is the extra processing that has to take place in order to pack/unpack the byte in the 4-byte word.

OTOH, if it were OK for `x` and `y` to be bigger than 1 byte (ie, if you don't rely on the variable overflowing as part of your algorithm), then you would be better off declaring them as `int`. You end up accessing 4 bytes every time even if your values are <256, which is wasteful, but no more so than the previous case. However, you no longer need to pack or unpack the variable, so that bit of overhead is gone.

The point is that if you simply declare `x` and `y` as `int`, you don't have to worry about alignment on a 32-bit architecture vs. a 64-bit architecture. The compiler will do the right thing either way.

Comment: So main reason behind having such a 'word-length' dependent data types is for efficiency? Compilers can then do some optimizations based on this?

Comment: Exactly. It's a little counter-intuitive, but larger data types can facilitate aligning variables to addresses which are faster to access. I'm adding another example to illustrate this point.